# How can i build shared and static library with the same name?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I want to build shared and static library with the same name but i have an error:

```
Android NDK: But this module was already defined by path/to/Android.mk
```

Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := j
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := j.c
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := j
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := j.c
include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

I want to publish shared and static library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := j_shared
LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME := libj
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := j.c
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := j
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := j.c
include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

Note that you *should* explicitly set the `lib` prefix, but *should not* provide the `.so` suffix.